# Visual C++ compiler giving wrong line reference for ambiguous symbol

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

The code is the following:

```
namespace n1
{
    template <class T>
    void n2();

    template <class T>
    void n2(T);
}

namespace n2 /* line 12 */
{
    class c {};
}

using namespace n1;

namespace n3
{
    void foo(n2::c);
}

void n3::foo(n2::c) /* line 24 */
{

}
```

When trying to compile it using the latest version of Visual C++ I get the following error:

```
1>test.cpp(24): error C2872: 'n2': ambiguous symbol
1>test.cpp(12): note: could be 'n2'
1>test.cpp(24): note: or       'n2'
```

Lines 12 and 24 are marked in the previous code piece with comments.

What is going on here? If I remove the definition of foo and declare a variable of type n2::c outside a function argument list it compiles just fine, I suppose that because the compiler figures out I'm refering to the class and not to any of the template functions. Also if instead I remove the second definition of the two n2 template functions inside the namespace n1 then the compiler gives me an error message, but referencing the correct lines: line 12 and the line where n2 is defined as a function (instead of line 24). Is this a compiler bug?

Comment: I have testet this code with various compilers:
VC++ 2015 does not compile and outputs wrong line numbers.
VC++ 2012 and 2013 do not compile but do not output line numbers at all (for the candidates).
gcc (various versions) do compile.
 - 
The line numbers are definetly buggy (seems to be a new feature in VC++ 2015) but I am not able to tell if this code should compile or not.

Comment: Nobody here can change this for you.  Report bugs and undesired compiler behavior at connect.microsoft.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Microsoft is correct here. Quoting the working C++ standard draft [$7.3.4.6](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.udir#6), it says

> If name lookup finds a declaration for a name in two different
>   namespaces, and the declarations do not declare the same entity and do
>   not declare functions, the use of the name is ill-formed....

Then it gives an example similar to yours, like this:

> ```
> namespace A {
>   class X { };
>   extern "C"   int g();
>   extern "C++" int h();
> }
> namespace B {
>   void X(int);
>   extern "C"   int g();
>   extern "C++" int h(int);
> }
> using namespace A;
> using namespace B;
>
> void f() {
>   X(1);             // error: name X found in two namespaces
>   g();              // OK: name g refers to the same entity
>   h();              // OK: overload resolution selects A::h
> }
> ```

Though, both gcc and clang accept the code. I think they are wrong here.

Go back to the quoted paragraph and note the line "*...do not declare the same entity and do not declare functions...*".

In your code, the name `n2` in the namespace `n1` is a function template and not a function. 
Because, a function template is not a function. See [$8.3.5.15](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct#15) (emphasis mine):

> A non-template function is a function that is not a function template
>   specialization. [ Note: **A function template is not a function.**  — end
>   note ]

To resolve your problem, qualify `n2` with a global namespace... like this

```
namespace n1
{
    template <class T>
    void n2();

    template <class T>
    void n2(T);
}

namespace n2 /* line 12 */
{
    class c {};
}

using namespace n1;

namespace n3
{
    void foo(::n2::c);
}

void n3::foo(::n2::c) /* line 24 */
{

}
```